# How do I handle user defined exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have an Error module defined containing my application defined exceptions as something like:

```
class Error(Exception):
        pass

class NoSchemaVersion(Error):
        def __init__(self):
                self.code = 1
                self.msg  = "No schema version specified"
        pass


class NoMsgType(Error):
        def __init__(self):
                self.code = 2
                self.msg = "No message type specified"
        pass
```

How do I would I handle specific exceptions when they are raised.  I tried something like:

```
import Error
errors = Error.Error()

try:
   <do some stuff>
except errors.NoMsgType:
   <stuff>
```

but I get the message:

```
AttributeError: 'Error' object has no attribute 'NoMsgType'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You handle them like you handle any other type of exception. What you really need to ask is how to import a type from a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Error.Error()` (stored in `error`) constructs a new value of the `Error` class, but `NoMsgType` is a separate class that isn't actually part of `Error`, and so `error.NoMsgType` doesn't exist.  To catch a `NoMsgType`, you should just write `except Error.NoMsgType:`.

Comment: `Error.NoMsgType` raises the error `AttributeError: type object 'Error' has no attribute 'NoMsgType'`.

Comment: @aj8uppal: Is your import statement still `import Error`, or are you running this in a context in which `Error` is the class rather than the module?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks from a relative python newbie

Answer (score 1):

I gues you need to do simething like this:

```
try:
    somecode
except Error.NoMsgType:
    morecode
```